# Plotting City Wise Data on World Map

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, plotly

So I have a Dictionary of Cities in World and Frequency of Events in them

For Example a small subset of Data

```
{'Iasi': 4, 'Reston': 38, 'Krakow': 2, 'Amsterdam': 103, 'Washington': 99, 'Madrid': 9, 'Tehran': 3, 'New Delhi': 2, 'Hanoi': 2, 'Johor': 3, 'Chicago': 3, 'W Sussex': 13, 'Shiraz': 2, 'Morelos': 2, 'New York': 49, 'Abingdon': 19, 'Basel': 17, 'Beijing': 51, 'Malden': 4, 'London': 47, 'Heidelberg': 14}
```

Now I want to plot this Data on World map to show how many events happen from which location

I found a code online to do similar kind of plotting for country wise data
(Data used in Code is not my Data)

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(12)
gapminder = px.data.gapminder().query("year==2007")
#gapminder['counts'] = np.nan

d = {'United States': [139421],
    'Canada': [21601], 
    'United Kingdom': [18314],
    'Germany': [17024],
    'Spain': [13096]}

yourdata = pd.DataFrame(d).T.reset_index()
yourdata.columns=['country', 'count']

df=pd.merge(gapminder, yourdata, how='left', on='country')

fig = px.choropleth(df, locations="iso_alpha",
                    color="count", 
                    hover_name="country", # column to add to hover information
                    color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Plasma)

fig.show()
```

But the Issue with this is it plots according to Country Names not city names does anyone know a way so that I can plot by city or any way to create a Country wise dictionary from the Dictionary of Cities given above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this

Used the Same Code above to Plot to Find Country Name from City name Just Used the Code Below

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

j={'Iasi': 4, 'Reston': 38, 'Krakow': 2, 'Amsterdam': 103, 'Washington': 99, 'Madrid': 9, 'Tehran': 3, 'New Delhi': 2, 'Hanoi': 2, 'Johor': 3, 'Chicago': 3, 'W Sussex': 13, 'Shiraz': 2, 'Morelos': 2, 'New York': 49, 'Abingdon': 19, 'Basel': 17, 'Beijing': 51, 'Malden': 4, 'London': 47, 'Heidelberg': 14}

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent = "geoapiExercises")
for i in j :
   location = geolocator.geocode(i)
   #print("Country Name: ", location)
   loc_dict=location.raw
   k=(loc_dict['display_name'].rsplit(',' , 1)[1])
```